# Hide or Remove vertical line in a specific point D3 chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I drew a multi series line using d3 and added a vertical line when mouse hover over points. And I want to hide the vertical line and the text in 2018 point which has no data. I don't know how to select the line at the specific point which is `translate(415,0)`, so I am not able to change the style to `display:none`;

Here is the code:

```js
var data =[
{
    'timescale': '2015', 
    'Not': 31, 
    'Nearly': 59, 
    'Standard': 81,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2016', 
  'Not': 28, 
    'Nearly': 55, 
    'Standard': 78,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2017', 
  'Not': 25, 
    'Nearly': 51, 
    'Standard': 75,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2018', 
 'Not': "null", 
    'Nearly': "null", 
    'Standard': "null",
    'Exceed':"null"
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2019', 
 'Not': 41, 
    'Nearly': 67, 
    'Standard': 90,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2020', 
'Not': 36, 
    'Nearly': 61, 
    'Standard': 86,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2021', 
'Not': 31, 
    'Nearly': 55, 
    'Standard': 82,
    'Exceed':100
  }
];






//d3.csv("test.csv", function(error,data){
  console.log(data);
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50 },  
    svg = d3.select('svg'),
    width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#BBB84B","#789952","#50DB51","#2D602A"]);

// define the line
var line = d3.line()
.defined(function (d) { 
      return !isNaN(d.total); 
    })
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.timescale); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.total); });


// scale the range of the data
z.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "timescale";
}));

var trends = z.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        timescale: d.timescale,
        total: +d[name]
      };
    })
  };
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.timescale; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(trends, function(c) {
  return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
    return v.total;
  });
})]);


// Draw the line
var trend = g.selectAll(".trend")
  .data(trends)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "trend");

trend.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.name); });

// Draw the empty value for every point
var points = g.selectAll('.points')
  .data(trends)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'points')
  .append('text');

// Draw the circle
trend
  .style("fill", "#FFF")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.name); })
  .selectAll("circle.line")
  .data(function(d){return d.values} )
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.timescale !== "2018" })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.timescale); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.total); });
  

// Draw the axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(6));

var focus = g.append('g')
  .attr('class','focus')
  .style('display', 'none');

focus.append('line')
  .attr('class', 'x-hover-line hover-line')
  .attr('y1' , 0)
  .attr('y2', height)
  .style('stroke',"black");

svg.append('rect')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);

// var timeScales = data.map(function(name) { return x(name.timescale); });
// console.log(timeScales);

var timeScales = [106,209,312,415,518,621,724];
// d3.select('.focus')
//       .attr("x1",415)
//       .attr("y1",0)
//       .attr("x2",415)
//       .attr("y2",height)
//       .style("display","none");

function mouseover() {
  
  focus.style("display", null);
  d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", null);
}
function mouseout() {
  focus.style("display", "none");
  d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", "none");
}
function mousemove() {
  var i = d3.bisect(timeScales, d3.mouse(this)[0], 1);
  var di = data[i-1];
  focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(di.timescale) + ",0)");

  d3.selectAll('.points text')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(di.timescale) + 5; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.values[i-1].total)-5; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.values[i-1].total; })
    .style('fill', function(d) { return z(d.name); });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.hover-line {

  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> you have using bisection as a tip

so it will draw only when it selected, lets change that so it will not draw the 2018 when mouseover it

```js
var data =[
{
    'timescale': '2015', 
    'Not': 31, 
    'Nearly': 59, 
    'Standard': 81,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2016', 
  'Not': 28, 
    'Nearly': 55, 
    'Standard': 78,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2017', 
  'Not': 25, 
    'Nearly': 51, 
    'Standard': 75,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2018', 
 'Not': "null", 
    'Nearly': "null", 
    'Standard': "null",
    'Exceed':"null"
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2019', 
 'Not': 41, 
    'Nearly': 67, 
    'Standard': 90,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2020', 
'Not': 36, 
    'Nearly': 61, 
    'Standard': 86,
    'Exceed':100
  },
  {
    'timescale': '2021', 
'Not': 31, 
    'Nearly': 55, 
    'Standard': 82,
    'Exceed':100
  }
];






//d3.csv("test.csv", function(error,data){
 // console.log(data);
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50 },  
    svg = d3.select('svg'),
    width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#BBB84B","#789952","#50DB51","#2D602A"]);

// define the line
var line = d3.line()
.defined(function (d) { 
      return !isNaN(d.total); 
    })
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.timescale); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.total); });


// scale the range of the data
z.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "timescale";
}));

var trends = z.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        timescale: d.timescale,
        total: +d[name]
      };
    })
  };
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.timescale; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(trends, function(c) {
  return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
    return v.total;
  });
})]);


// Draw the line
var trend = g.selectAll(".trend")
  .data(trends)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "trend");

trend.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.name); });

// Draw the empty value for every point
var points = g.selectAll('.points')
  .data(trends)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'points')
  .append('text');

// Draw the circle
trend
  .style("fill", "#FFF")
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.name); })
  .selectAll("circle.line")
  .data(function(d){return d.values} )
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.timescale !== "2018" })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.timescale); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.total); });
  

// Draw the axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(6));

var focus = g.append('g')
  .attr('class','focus')
  .style('display', 'none');

focus.append('line')
  .attr('class', 'x-hover-line hover-line')
  .attr('y1' , 0)
  .attr('y2', height)
  .style('stroke',"black");

svg.append('rect')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);

// var timeScales = data.map(function(name) { return x(name.timescale); });
// console.log(timeScales);

var timeScales = [106,209,312,415,518,621,724];
// d3.select('.focus')
//       .attr("x1",415)
//       .attr("y1",0)
//       .attr("x2",415)
//       .attr("y2",height)
//       .style("display","none");

function mouseover() {

  focus.style("display", null);
  d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", null);
}
function mouseout() {
  focus.style("display", "none");
  d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", "none");
}
function mousemove() {
  var i = d3.bisect(timeScales, d3.mouse(this)[0], 1);
  var di = data[i-1];
  console.log(di)
  if (di.timescale =="2018"){
  focus.style('display','none')
    d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", "none");
  }else{
  focus.style('display','block')
  d3.selectAll('.points text').style("display", "block");
  focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(di.timescale) + ",0)");}

  d3.selectAll('.points text')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(di.timescale) + 5; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.values[i-1].total)-5; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.values[i-1].total; })
    .style('fill', function(d) { return z(d.name); });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.hover-line {

  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mousemove function only perform the transformation if timescale is not 2018:

```
function mousemove() {
  var i = d3.bisect(timeScales, d3.mouse(this)[0], 1);
  var di = data[i-1];

  if (di.timescale !== '2018') {
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(di.timescale) + ",0)");

    d3.selectAll('.points text')
      .attr('x', function(d) { return x(di.timescale) + 5; })
      .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.values[i-1].total)-5; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.values[i-1].total; })
      .style('fill', function(d) { return z(d.name); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I also fixed it today. Instead of using di.timescale I used i !==4. In your code, when you hover on 2018, the point text of 2017 didn't disappear, so it would be better do a if else statement I think. And here is my code:

Comment: '
if(i !== 4){
 focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(di.timescale) + ",0)");

focus.style("display",null);
d3.selectAll('.points text')
      .style("display",null);
  d3.selectAll('.points text')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(di.timescale) + 5; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.values[i-1].total)-5; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.values[i-1].total; })
    .style('fill', function(d) { return z(d.name); });
}else{
   focus.style("display","none");
   d3.selectAll('.points text')
      .style("display","none");'

Comment: I see, only the 2018 point text disappears. The if else works better in this case as you point out. Please don't forget to vote up the answer if you believe it helped.